# Create a Django detail view

Tags: python, django

How can I create a detailed view for the user to create a profile template. From what I gather from the documentation

views.py

```
 `from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

  class UserDetailView(DetailView):
      model = User
      template_name= "app/user_detail.html`
```

urls.py

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'(P<id>)/$', views.ClassDetailView.as_view(), name=user_profile),]
```

But it needs a slug in order to work is there a way to change that to the user id, username(prefered) or some other alternative? what would the urls.py would look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can define [`get_object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) in your class to return the object to display.

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name= "app/user_detail.html"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```